# How to power the microcontroller in a BMS of a large battery pack

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, battery-charging

Yeah, it's a short and simple question but I couldn't find an answer on google.

Just imagine I got a lots of LiIons in series , about 400 Volt for use in an electric vehicle.

I use some ICs to control 12 or 16cells each (they power from those cells). But everything of course must be isolated from each other and the µc of course.

How will the µc be powered ? 400 Volt DC -> AC -> 5V AC -> 5V DC cant be a solution.
Maybe they use a separate cell just for the µc and stuff? But how would that one get charged then?
And just powering it from the 2 bottom cells would imbalance the stack.. or not?

Comment: use a dc to dc isolating converter - the amount of current taken from a couple of cells is small compared to the current taken for a vehicle. http://circuits.linear.com/553

Answer (score 1):

Most electric vehicles either have a DC->DC converter or a separate battery to power 12V components. I would go that way.

I really wouldn't want to be building something to deal with 400VDC.